# Is this dual behavior allowed in integration in Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The integral $$I_1 = \int_{C} \bar zdz=4\pi i 
,$$ when $C$ is the right-hand half $z=2e^{iθ},\ (-\dfrac{π}{2}≤θ≤\dfrac{π}{2})$, of the circle  $|z| =2$ from $z =-2i$ to $z = 2i$. And, one also can show the integral $$I_2 = \int_{C} \dfrac {1}{z}dz=\pi i ,$$ holds for the same $C$.

Is this argument true? : Since $z \bar z = |z|^2=4$ so $$4 \pi i = 4\int_{C} \dfrac {1}{z}dz = z \bar z \int_{C} \dfrac {1}{z}dz= \int_{C} z \bar z\dfrac {1}{z}dz = \int_{C} \bar zdz=4\pi i.$$

In other words, $z \bar z$ is constant so it can 'pass into' the integral but it can't cancel out $z$ in the denominator as now it behaves as a function. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that on the given circle $z\bar z$ is a constant, and as long as you make sure that you're only dealing with values strictly on the circle (i. e. neither off the circle, nor differentiating away from the circle), you can interchange it with that constant. You *are* actually cancelling out the $z$ in the denominator, so I'm not sure what you mean by "but it can't cancel out $z$ in the denominator as now it behaves as a function".

Comment: My question is can I cancel the two $z$'s ? When we entered $z$ it was 'part' of $z \bar z$ and $z \bar z$ is constant allowed to enter. But when $z$ 'separates' from $\bar z$ and become non-constant we should've not allowed it to pass into the integral at the beginning. Am I right?

Comment: @L.G.: No, you're not. There's nothing magic about the $z\bar z$. You introduced it in a perfectly valid manner. All you have to ensure is that you consider it strictly only on the circle and neither explicitly, nor implicitly (e.g. by differentiation) away from the circle. You're doing that. So there's no reason why the $z\bar z$ should have to stick together, or why you shouldn't be allowed to cancel the two $z$'s.

Comment: I think it is allowed from this comparison to the real-variable integral: You may write $\frac{x}{x}$ which is $1$ then multiply either $\frac{1}{x}$ or $x$ for simplification of integral?

Comment: @L.G.: Could you elaborate on that? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I was saying that is like writing $\int f(x) dx$ as $\int \dfrac {x}{x} f(x) dx$ then write $\int x\times \dfrac {1}{x} f(x) dx$. There is no specially or caution with complex variable case if we limit all to the mentioned circle. ?

Comment: I meant that I got what said. I was just trying to illustrate similar situation with a real variable case. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @L.G.: Well, the $\frac xx$ example is a bit more general, because that's valid whenever $x\ne0$. Yes, no special caution is required for the complex variable. The only caution required is to be aware that you can go off a constraint not just explicitly (which is easy to avoid) but also implicitly e.g. by differentiating (which effectively considers values in a neighbourhood, even if you're only calculating the derivative on the circle).